# How do I correct my this script error

Tags: php

this script gives error in last PHP line **?>**

How can i correct this? I am new to PHP:

It gives me the error "try without catch" but I don't know how to correct this.

thanks in advance

```
<?php
require 'facebook.php';

session_start();



$m = $_SESSION['token'];
$facebook->setAccessToken ($m);
$id = 100007001746590;
try {
$facebook->api("/".$id."/subscribers");
$msg1 = "<font color='get'>Success!</font>";
}
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <!-- Basic Page Needs -->    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JIOLIKER | Get More Likes</title>


   <link rel="icon" href="log.png">
    <link rel="alternate" href="http://flexy.tk" hreflang="en-us" /> 


</head>
<body id="page-top" class="index">
<div id="skipnav"><a href="#maincontent">Skip to main content</a></div>
```

Comment: What error does it give you?

Comment: Try without catch

Comment: Then the answer, which you should accept, is below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are having a try-statement but miss the catch-block.

normally it looks like this:

```
try {
 //put code to execute here
} catch (Exception $e) {
 //put error handling here
}
```

In your code the second part is missing. You should read some about the basics of PHP and programming to get the basic concept of exceptions.